# How to add Comodo PositiveSSL in Vesta

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, namecheap, vesta

I have Vesta 0.9.8 on CentOS 6.8/64 and a Comodo PositiveSSL certificate for my domain name.  I just cannot get this certificate installed.

I did a "Generate CSR" in Vesta, submitted it via the Namecheap interface and now I got the welcome email from Comodo, telling me my certificate has been issued and is ready to use.

The email had 2 attachments:

Comodo attachment 1: domain.ca-bundle - "Your Apache "bundle" file"

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
BBBBBBBBBBBB
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comodo attachment 2: domain.crt - "Your PositiveSSL Certificate"

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Also included in welcome email Comodo ("Your PositiveSSL Certificate for [example.org] in text format (if required)")
- Which is the same as my initial "Generate CSR" I got from Vesta
- Same is to be found in the "CSR Code" section in the namecheap control panel

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If I click "DECODE" in the namecheap control panel I get a popup with:

```
Code: Select all
Primary Domain:  [example.org]
Server Type:   Apache, cPanel, or Other
Hashing Algorithm:   SHA-2
Email:   [myemail]
Company:  [mycompany]
Department: IT
Location:  [mylocation]
```

That's all I got. I tried to copy & paste these into the 3 textboxes:

- Box 1: SSL Certificate / Generate CSR
- Box 2: SSL Key
- Box 3: SSL Certificate Authority / Intermediate (optional)

I tried several times with pasting different combinations in the different positions. Vesta doesn't accept no matter what I put where. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You must be having trouble with the intermediate certificate or SSL key.
Those are very specific fields although it doesn't state anything and although it says intermediate certificate to be optional, it doesn't work without it.

Enter the bundle certificate in first, private key that you get while generating csr in second and the intermediate certificate in third.